# Cannot put into Java map with generic key type and nested generic value type

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, collections

I have a generics compilation failure where I've created a map with key values types that use generics and then I try to put into that map.

Let me lay out the code before I ask the question. I've simplified the code as much as possible for this question.

Here's all the code that compiles.

```
public interface Cache {
}

public class ExampleCache implements Cache {
}

public interface Item {
}

public class ExampleItem implements Item {
}

public interface Loader<C extends Cache> {
    void load(C cache);
}

public class ExampleLoader<C extends Cache> implements Loader<ExampleCache> {

    @Override
    public void load(ExampleCache cache) {
    }

}
```

And here's the class that does not compile.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Registry {

    private final Map<String, Cache> caches = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Loader<Cache>> loaders = new HashMap<>();

    public Registry() {

        caches.put("cache1", new ExampleCache());

        Loader<ExampleCache> exampleLoader = new ExampleLoader<>();

        // PROBLEM LINE: this line does not compile
        // there is a red underline under 'exampleLoader'
        loaders.put("cache1", exampleLoader);

    }

    public void loadAll() {

        for (Map.Entry<String, Loader<Cache>> entry : loaders.entrySet()) {
            String cacheName = entry.getKey();
            Loader<Cache> loader = entry.getValue();
            Cache cache = caches.get(cacheName);
            loader.load(cache);
        }

    }

}
```

The error I get is below.

```
Error:(19, 31) java: incompatible types: Loader<ExampleCache> cannot be converted to Loader<Cache>
```

What am I doing wrong? Please explain your reasoning so that I may gain a deeper understanding of what I'm doing wrong. Also, when proposing a solution, please check that all the code above compiles. I've had cases where if I fix one area then another breaks.

Thank you.

**Edit1**: Someone suggested changing the loader map declaration to:

```
private final Map<String, Loader<? extends Cache>> loaders = new HashMap<>();
```

But this breaks the loadAll() method below it.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Registry {

    private final Map<String, Cache> caches = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Loader<? extends Cache>> loaders = new HashMap<>();

    public Registry() {

        caches.put("cache1", new ExampleCache());

        Loader<ExampleCache> exampleLoader = new ExampleLoader<>();

        loaders.put("cache1", exampleLoader);

    }

    public void loadAll() {

        for (Map.Entry<String, Loader<? extends Cache>> entry : loaders.entrySet()) {

            String cacheName = entry.getKey();
            Loader<? extends Cache> loader = entry.getValue();
            Cache cache = caches.get(cacheName);

            // NEW PROBLEM LINE: this line does not compile
            loader.load(cache);

        }

    }

}
```

The new compilation error is:

```
Error:(26, 25) java: incompatible types: Cache cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Cache
```

**Edit 2**: It looks like Andy Turner's solution worked! While it hides the load inside the new class it looks like this is the happiest working compromise I can have.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Registry {

    static class CacheLoader<C extends Cache> {

        final C cache;
        final Loader<C> loader;

        CacheLoader(C cache, Loader<C> loader) {
            this.cache = cache;
            this.loader = loader;
        }

        public void load() {
            loader.load(cache);
        }

    }

    private final Map<String, CacheLoader<?>> cacheLoaders = new HashMap<>();

    public Registry() {
        cacheLoaders.put("cache1", new CacheLoader<>(new ExampleCache(), new ExampleLoader<>()));
    }

    public void loadAll() {
        for (CacheLoader<?> cacheLoader : cacheLoaders.values()) {
            cacheLoader.load();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `Map<String, Loader<? extends Cache>> loaders`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thanks for your comment. That fixes the problem line but breaks the loadAll() method below it. The error is: "Error:(26, 25) java: incompatible types: Cache cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Cache". Like I said in the question please ensure that your solution works with all the code.

Comment: That's just the starting point. Your `ExampleLoader` doesn't accept any kind of Cache, it can only accept `ExampleCache`. You have an implicit relationship between `caches` and `loaders`, in that `loaders.get(foo).load(caches.get(foo))` should be valid. I don't know how you enforce this invariant.

Comment: You only put a `Loader<ExampleLoader>` into the `loaders` map, so why not `Map<String, Loader<ExampleLoader>>`?

Comment: @AndyTurner although it isn't shown in the example above - it is intended to have other types of loaders in there also :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your two maps:

```
private final Map<String, Cache> caches = new HashMap<>();
private final Map<String, Loader<Cache>> loaders = new HashMap<>();
```

are essentially parallel, in that the `Cache` and `Loader<Cache>` for the same key are meant to be used together.

So, store them together:

```
private final Map<String, Together<?>> togethers = new HashMap<>();

togethers.put(new Together<>(new ExampleCache(), new ExampleLoader<>()));
```

where the `Together` class is something like:

```
class Together<C extends Cache> {
  private final C cache;
  private final Loader<C> loader;

  // Constructor.

  void load() {
    loader.load(cache);
  }
}
```

In this way, it doesn't matter that it's a `Together<?>`, you don't need to know that type in order to invoke the `load()` method safely.

Comment: Your `Together` class can be written as `record Together<C extends Cache>(C cache, Loader<C> loader) { void load() {loader.load(cache); } }` with java 14 records.

Comment: Hi Andy. That worked perfectly. I've posted my modified code above. You were the first person to post the solution that I adopted. I'm in two minds about the Together class in terms of design but it looks like this is the only way it's going to work without casts or compile errors. I've accepted your answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a `Loader<ExampleCache>` is not a `Loader<Cache>`.

A `Loader<Cache>` can accept any `Cache` as parameter for it's `.load()` method, while a `Loader<ExampleCache>` can only accept `ExampleCache`s.

From your code I can infer that there is a relationship between `loaders` and `caches`, in particular, the following invariant should hold:

```
loaders.get(foo).load(caches.get(foo));
```

This should be valid, but you will have a hard time to prove this.

To solve this, you either need some unchecked casts, or use a different design.

- For the unchecked cast solution, you better have a method that enforces this invariant:

  ```
  private final Map<String, Cache> caches = new HashMap<>();
  private final Map<String, Loader<? extends Cache>> loaders = new HashMap<>();
  private <C extends Cache> void putIntoRegisty(String name, C cache, Loader<? super C> loader) {
      caches.put(name, cache);
      loaders.put(name, loader);
  }
  ```

  Only ever modify `caches` using that (or similar) methods. (You can add one that removes the cache and loader, for example).
  The important part is: Because you only have a small portion of code where you modify the maps, you will have it easier time to convince yourself and others that the invariant holds.

  Now to the gory `loadAll`:

  ```
  public void loadAll() {

      for (Map.Entry<String, Loader<? extends Cache>> entry : loaders.entrySet()) {
          String cacheName = entry.getKey();
          // This is safe, see putIntoRegistry
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          Loader<Cache> loader = (Loader<Cache>) entry.getValue();
          Cache cache = caches.get(cacheName);
          loader.load(cache);
      }
  }
  ```
- The second option is to use ONE map for both key and value:

  ```
  // A Java 14 record would be better better...
  private static class CacheAndLoader<C extends Cache> {
      C cache;
      Loader<C> loader;
      void load() {
          loader.load(cache);
      }           
  }
  private final Map<String, CacheAndLoader<? extends Cache>> cachesAndLoaders = new HashMap<>();
  private <C extends Cache> void putIntoRegisty(String name, C cache, Loader<C> loader) {
      CacheAndLoader<C> cal = new CacheAndLoader<>();
      cal.cache = cache;
      cal.loader = loader;
      cachesAndLoaders.put(name, cal);
  }


  public void loadAll() {
      for (CacheAndLoader<? extends Cache> cal : cachesAndLoaders.values()) {
          cal.load();
      }
  }
  ```

  We don't need any unchecked casts here, but this comes at a small price: An additional data class. I put it inside the `Registry`, but your code style might require it to be in it's own file.

Comment: Hi Johannes. Thanks for your extensive contributions. Andy had already proposed your option 2 solution earlier and I adopted it. I've posted my modified code above. However I like your idea about making it a inner static class - which I think I'll adopt too. As Andy's solution was posted earlier and I had adopted it prior to seeing your comment I've accepted his answer. Many thanks for your answer which I've upvoted.

Comment: Yeah, took me a while to write both approaches and test them. No hard feelings. Also see my comment under Andy's answer. Once records are in standard java and you use that version, you can replace your entire class with the few lines I wrote there. The usage is similar as with your class. Benefit is the reduced mental overhead.

Comment: Np - yours was definitely the most comprehensive answer so worth the time spent on it. As for records - that's a great tip. I'm stuck on 11 for now but if I move to 14 I will make this change. Thanks!

Comment: In 14 it's just a preview feature - so, you might need or want to wait until it is in standard java. That being said, this is one of the use cases records were designed for.